# Selecting two distinct column with one max date

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sybase

I have a table like this:

```
ID  DATE        TableName  
X   29-Jan-12   A  
X   29-Feb-12   B  
X   29-Jan-12   C  
Y   18-Nov-12   A  
Z   18-Nov-14   C  
X   17-Nov-13   D  
Z   14-May-12   A  
Y   18-Nov-13   D
```

I want to fetch unique ID with MaxDate so that output should be like this-

```
ID  DATE    TableName  
Z   18-Nov-14   C  
Y   18-Nov-13   D  
X   17-Nov-13   D
```

I am using `select ID, MAX(DATE), TableName from table` but that is not giving me the desired output.

Comment: What is the RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Lesson here: If you don't choose the correct DB product, someone who is an expert in another product may close your question. @Barmar closed the question and linked to an older one that is specific to MySQL; none of the answers that exist in Oracle (for example) but not in MySQL are shown in that older question, but who cares. Not Barmar, clearly.

Comment: Here's an Oracle duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column?rq=1

Comment: There are numerous other similar questions listed in the **Related** sidebar.

Comment: @Barmar - the lesson for the OP remains. Always pay attention to tags, don't just use the defaults SO places there for you.

Comment: I also suspect the MySQL solutions will work in Oracle and Sybase.

Comment: @Barmar - lol at the linked answers for Oracle. I did find the most efficient answer (eventually), which is Oracle specific with no analog in MySQL - the answer I gave in this thread. It took me about three times as long to find that answer in the older thread than it took me to write the full answer here. Another problem with old threads (that one is eight years old) is that at least in Oracle, new features, optimizations etc. are added at least every 2-3 years, so many "better" solution can't possibly be found in old threads. That's a problem with the whole concept of "duplicate questions".

Comment: @mathguy The OP still hasn't answered which database he's actually using, so who knows if that answer is even relevant. A generic solution that works in any database should be an acceptable answer, even if it's not optimal for a specific DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a in clause on a subselect group by
If you are using a db that allow tuple

```
select id, date, tableName 
from my_table 
where (id, date) in (select id, max(date) 
                     from my_table 
                     group by id);
```

or if the db don't allow tuple you can use an inner join

```
select id, date, tableName 
from my_table a 
inner join ( select id, max(date) max_date 
                     from my_table 
                     group by id) t on t.id = a.id and  t.max_date = a.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle** answer:

What you are missing is picking up the `tablename` that corresponds to the `max(date)` within each group.

That is done most efficiently with `keep (dense_rank last...)` like so: (note - DATE is a reserved word in Oracle so I hope your column name is not DATE and you used that just as a placeholder...)

```
select   id, max(date) as date, 
         max(tablename) keep (dense_rank last order by date) as tablename
from     table_like_this
group by id;
```

Oracle documentation (for FIRST but read the text, it refers also to LAST)
https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641